# How to add user defined navigation in Mura 7

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, mura

I'm using Mura 7 and want to add used defined navigation. I've designed the new navigation, as per the client wishes. I want to add that into inline edit navigation drag & drop options. Is that possible? Could someone let me know how to do it? Thanks in advance!

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Check the documentation here - [Custom Display Object Configurators](http://docs.getmura.com/v7/mura-ui-markup-conventions/custom-display-object-configurators/)

Comment: Yes.configurator.cfm file helped me to did it. Thank you @Miguel-F.

Comment: I'm glad that helped you. Please add what you did as an answer to your own question here. It is okay to do that.  That way it will help other people with the same question.